# Drag and Drop nested list

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I have a list of fruits and a list of baskets. I need to pick one fruit and place it in one basket. I used [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd) to implement the drag and drop concept. but i couldn't place the fruit at one basket. If i drag and drop a fruit into a basket, all the baskets gets that fruit.

I know the problem lies in this line, i should not use same name `fruit` for every basket. I need to assign it dynamically. or is there any better way of doing it. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

```
<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruitsInBasket; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{fruit.name}}</li>
```

**Here is my code:**

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  listBaskets: Array<Basket> = [
    {
      id: 1, name: 'Basket 1'
    }, {
      id: 2, name: 'Basket 2'
    }, {
      id: 3, name: 'Basket 3'
    }, {
      id: 4, name: 'Basket 4'
    },];
  listFruits: Array<Fruit> = [
    {
      id: 1, name: 'Apple'
    }, {
      id: 2, name: 'Orange'
    }, {
      id: 3, name: 'Mango'
    }, {
      id: 4, name: 'Strawberry'
    },];
  fruitsInBasket: Array<Fruit> = [];
  constructor() { }

}

export interface Basket {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
export interface Fruit {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Available Baskets
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <div class="panel panel-warning" *ngFor="let basket of listBaskets; let boxer=index">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              {{basket.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="fruitsInBasket">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li *ngFor="let fruit of fruitsInBasket; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{fruit.name}}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Fruits
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listFruits">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li *ngFor="let fruit of listFruits; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{fruit.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Seeing this question after 3 years. makes me realize how dumb I was in the beginning :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem

```
// app.component.ts
...
fruitsInBasket: Array<Fruit> = [];
```

You are storing the same data for all the boxes, so when you drop a fruit in one of them, you drop it in all of them.

Consider changing the type of `fruitsInBasket` to

```
// app.component.ts
... 
fruitsInBasket: { [basket: number]: Array<Fruit> };
```

and rewriting the component, keeping in mind that you're maintaining a separate datastore for each basket.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing the same fruit in all the baskets is because you are using just one `fruitsInBasket` Array to store fruits for all of them.

The best way to accomplish this is to use separate Arrays for each of the baskets and push the dropped fruit on `onDropSuccess` of the droppable. Check out the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd#5-transfer-custom-data-via-drag-and-drop).