# Angular6 Recursive List Drag and Drop CDK

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material-6, angular-cdk

I am looking to get a nested recursive list working in drag and drop. What I am trying to accomplish is where an item from an inner nested list can move into any other nested list or into its own group. The problem is I have been looking at a number of different examples and questions from Stack here and there has not been a successful idea to get this to work.

Here are some of the questions and examples I have looked at:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-connected-lists)

[Stackoverflow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120167/angular-7-dragdrop-nested-lists-with-native-cdk)

[Stackoverflow #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968459/drag-and-drop-nested-list)

[Stackoverflow #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166120/angular-dragdrop-containers-and-items)

So you can have an idea here is a sample of my data:
[image: data]

Where each Area can have children, each child could have children as well. So this creates the nested data.

In my Angular component, I am using recursion to recreate the levels each time check out this example:

component.ts:

```
dropGroup(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  let area = event.item.data;
  console.log('group', area, event)
}

dropItem(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  let area = event.item.data;
  console.log('item', area, event)
}
```

component.html:

```
<div cdkDropList #parentList="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropGroup($event)" [cdkDropListData]="areas">
  <div cdkDropListGroup class="area-wrapper" *ngFor="let area of areas;" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="area">
    <div class="area-list">
      <div [ngClass]="area.children.length ? 'area-toggle' : 'area'" [style.paddingLeft.px]="area.level > 1 ? area.level*15 : 0">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
          <div class="top-toggle" *ngIf="area.children.length">
            <mat-icon (click)="showChildren(area)" *ngIf="!area.showToggle">keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="showChildren(area)" *ngIf="area.showToggle">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <span class="area-name">{{ area.name }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="area-buttons">
          <button class="area-button area-add" mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(area)">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button class="area-button area-edit" mat-icon-button (click)="editArea(area)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button class="area-button area-delete" mat-icon-button (click)="deletingArea($event, area, area.name)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button cdkDragHandle class="drag-handle" mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>drag_handle</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle-children" *ngIf="area.showToggle" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">
        <sp-area-list
        *ngIf="area.children"
        [areas]="area.children"
        (deleteArea)="deletingArea($event, area)"
        (addingArea)="addNewItem($event)"
        (editingArea)="editArea($event)">
        </sp-area-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time I try different examples the drag and drop console only shows the container that the item started from not where it moved to... no examples have been working or have helped me solve what I am trying to accomplish.

Anyone had success with nested recursive lists with CDK drag and drop?

Thanks for your help!